# "One another" for an ordered series of events

Tags: pronouns

> According to a traditional rule, *each other* denotes a reciprocal
> relation between two entities, and *one another* refers to more than
> two.
>
> Many people maintain a further stylistic distinction between the two
> expressions by using ***one another*** when an ordered series of
> events or stages is involved, as in *The waiters followed ***one
> another*** into the room*.
>
> https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=each+other

Why is it a "further" distinction?

Doesn't a series of events imply more than two "events" and therefore more than two "entities"?

Comment: Are you asking about "further" or "one another"? You've highlighted one, but asked a question about the other

Answer (score 2):

When you say 'all of my cousins hate one another', or 'all the guests looked at one another', you are discussing a reciprocal thing (each cousin hates all of the others and they all hate him or her, each guest looked at all of the others, and they all looked at him or her).

When you say 'The waiters followed one another into the room' or 'the summer days followed one another', there is no one-to-all reciprocal relationship. Each waiter or day, apart from the last, is followed by one other, and each, apart from the first, follows one other. That's the 'further' distinction.

Comment: I had thought of maybe even just two waiters alternating their presence at bussing tables for the whole service